# R - unique() gives 'incomparables != FALSE' error

Tags: r, sorting, unique

I have a (11590 x 2) df with two factor variables (values, ind), as follows:

```
> head(df)
          values  ind
8632   acanthite X138
40132  acanthite X638
1     actinolite   X1
1387  actinolite  X23
1765  actinolite  X29
1891  actinolite  X31
```

When I try to get all the unique values, why do I get the following error? How should I get around this error to get a df with only the records for unique values? Any help would be appreciated.

```
> unidf<-unique(df,"values")
Error: argument 'incomparables != FALSE' is not used (yet)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

R is interpreting the second parameter to your call to `unique()` as the value of `incomparables`.  Your call is being interpreted as this:

```
unidf<-unique(df, incomparables="values")
```

If you want to get unique rows from your data frame using only the `values` column then try this:

```
unidff <- df[!duplicated(df$values), ]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want a tidyverse friendly solution you can also replace `unique` with `dplyr::distinct` and your code as it stands should also work.

You could use:

```
library(dplyr)
unidf <- distinct(df,values)
```